# Multithreading works with a self made parrallel loop, but not with the native one

Tags: 2013, development

In a project, I have a quite complex operation that takes few seconds to execute. The operation requires to work with a `SPListItem` object.

Because my operation has to be executed with a bunch of different listitems, I ran the process in a parallel loop.

I know that sharepoint objects are not thread safe, so I reopen a new SPSite in each threads.

My parralelize method is, by now, a self made method (because the code is inherited from a SP2010 projet).

The code is working well when migrated to SP 2013.

However, to reduce custom code base, I want to **migrate the custom parrallel loop to the .Net 4. `AsParrallel().ForAll()` native multithreading library.**

But as soon as I migrate the code, **it starts to fail with `AccessDenied` exception**.

**What can cause this error? How to solve it?**

Here is the code:

## Get my job data:

```
var itemsToAnalyse= from SPListItem myItem in myList.Items

                    let fileName = myItem .File.Name
                    let fieldValue = new myItem["SomeField"]
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = webPartItem.ID,
                        FileName = fileName,
                        FieldValue= fieldValue
                    };
```

## My operation, ran using custom parrallel loop (**working**):

```
ParrallelUtilities.EachParallel(
    itemsToAnalyse,item =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var localSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
            {
                var localWeb = localSite.RootWeb;
                var localList = localWeb.Lists["MyList"];
                var localItem = localList.GetItemById(widget.Id);

                PerformActualJob(localItem); // Call my method, using a thread-specific splistitem
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw;
        }
    });
```

## Same operation, but using the out of the box task parallel library (**not working**):

```
itemsToAnalyse.AsParallel().ForAll(item =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var localSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
            {
                var localWeb = localSite.RootWeb;
                var localList = localWeb.Lists["MyList"];
                var localItem = localList.GetItemById(widget.Id);

                PerformActualJob(localItem); // Call my method, using a thread-specific splistitem
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw;
        }
    });
```

## FYI, here is the code of the custom parallel loop:

```
public static class ParrallelUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerates through each item in a list in parallel
    /// </summary>
    public static void EachParallel<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
    {
        // enumerate the list so it can't change during execution
        list = list.ToArray();
        var count = list.Count();

        if (count == 0)            {                return;            }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            // if there's only one element, just execute it
            action(list.First());
        }
        else
        {
            // Launch each method in it's own thread
            const int MaxHandles = 64;
            for (var offset = 0; offset <= count / MaxHandles; offset++)
            {
                // break up the list into 64-item chunks because of a limitiation in WaitHandle
                var chunk = list.Skip(offset * MaxHandles).Take(MaxHandles);

                // Initialize the reset events to keep track of completed threads
                var resetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[chunk.Count()];

                // spawn a thread for each item in the chunk
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var item in chunk)
                {
                    resetEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((object data) =>
                    {
                        int methodIndex = (int)((object[])data)[0];

                        // Execute the method and pass in the enumerated item
                        action((T)((object[])data)[1]);

                        // Tell the calling thread that we're done
                        resetEvents[methodIndex].Set();
                    }), new object[] { i, item });
                    i++;
                }

                // Wait for all threads to execute
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(resetEvents);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by the fact that PLINQ functions do not propagate identity of the calling thread to its worker threads as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319439/does-the-thread-identity-get-transferred-when-using-plinq-extensions). This may cause the security exception. Try the technique suggested in the link to propagate the context.